# patindex parterns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to trim a column (ActionOutput) to only show two substrings in that column.

I need to only show the 8 characters entries that starts with either WRD or CAS.

The column can have any types/numbers of characters and they won't always contains entries with the specified patterns.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  
 TSRPT_C009 = ExecutionTime,  
 LastStatusMessageID, 
 LastStatusMessageIDName, 
 TSRPT_C007 = ExitCode, 
 TSRPT_C008 = ActionOutput,
(PATINDEX('%[cas][wrd]%',ActionOutput)) AS CASID
```

FROM v_TaskExecutionStatus tse

I also tried this:

```
substring(
(substring(ActionOutput,(CHARINDEX('WRD0',ActionOutput)),8)),(CHARINDEX('CAS0',ActionOutput)),8
) AS CASID
```

But it also didn't work for the second pattern.

Is there a way to search for multiples patterns in a string (returned from a select) and return it/them.

Thks in advance and don't heistate if you have any questions.

Steph

Answer (score 0):

`PATINDEX()` returns an integer, not a string. You might try this:

```
(case when ActionOutput like '%cas%'
      then substring(ActionOutput, charindex('cas', ActionOutput), 8)
      when ActionOutput like '%wrd%'
      then substring(ActionOutput, charindex('wrd', ActionOutput), 8)
 end) as caswrd_8
```